# Using SilverStripe framework to consuming Soap API

Tags: php, soap, silverstripe

I haven’t found any document of consuming Soap API in SilverStripe. Do I need to include any add-on or module to achieve that. Is there any one who can share an example of that? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SilverStripe 3 you can use [RestfulService](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/integration/restfulservice/), however it has been deprecated and removed in SilverStripe 4.

You'd be best off creating your own implementation using something like [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/).

Short answer: you'll need to implement something yourself to retrieve data from a SOAP API.

Comment: Thanks for the replying. Actually, we are using a CWP instance (which should be built on SilverStripe 3) and interact with the back-end by Soap API. If using RestfulService, do I need to do additional implementation or it works out of box? Cheers!

Comment: Ok yeah CWP 1.x comes with RestfulService out of the box. You can use it immediately, but you'll still need to write your own handling of the results. It's designed to be an HTTP request client, but not SOAP specifically.

Comment: You can use PHP's built-in `SoapClient` to communicate with SOAP servers: http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php